# AngularJS - i18n and lang in the URL

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting, internationalization

I am currently on a project that needs to be multilingual.
The project is based on a PHP server (could'nt use NodeJS) and the front-end is written with AngularJS.

Right now, my language is only set by a cookie, and my whole application is translated by [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate).

For SEO purpose, I would like my URL to look like:
www.mywebsite.com/LANG_PARAMETER/anypage

I don't really know how to combine AngularJS with URL rewriting or anything else like this, I am searching since yesterday but couldn't find any track to follow.

I think that [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) could fit my needs, but I haven't time to rewrite my whole application using this module (it will be done later).

So if you have any idea...

Thank you!

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing, I have an answer to propose but I'm not sure that's the right one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512561/how-to-deal-with-djangocms-i18n-urls-en-my-page-fr-my-page-and-angularjs